# Is it true that the sum of squares of perpendicular medians in a triangle is equal to the square of the third median?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, triangles, median

I am aware of the fact that two medians are perpendicular in a triangle if and only if the

> Sum of the squares of the lengths of the sides to which these medians
> are drawn is $5$ times greater than the squared length of the third
> side.

However, I was also able to get the result that

> Sum of squares of perpendicular medians $=$ Square of the third median

Can someone please confirm if my result is true or not as I was not able to get any answer from looking up on the web? Please help!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Your result is true. (Congratulations on the discovery!) ... One way to prove it is to draw a figure and find in it a right triangle each of whose sides is two-thirds the length of a median. (Use the fact that the centroid divides a median in the ratio $1:2$.) ... That said, you should include your proof of the result in your question, so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand.

Comment: As said in the previous comment, your conclusion is correct. Please show how you got to the result and may be some of us can show alternate way to get to the result.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was trying to add the proof but I was not able to add a triangle with all the notations here in my question. I will try to take a snap of my triangle from my notebook and then add that over here.

Comment: Do the three medians form another triangle? If so, then the result follows from the Pythagorean Theorem.